# Indian currency format using C

Tags: c, formatting, floating-point

Indian Currency format is `12345` → "12,345" (for odd length) and `123456` → "1,23,456" (for even length). I have included all possibilities such as

1. Minus sign: "-12,345"
2. Decimal Point: "-12,345.345" or "12,345.123"
3. Zero Condition `000000.123` → "0.123"
4. Minus and Zero Condition '-000000.123' -> "-0.123"

```
int main()
{
    char        currency[20];
    char        *tmpCurrency=NULL;
    int         length = 0;
    int         j = 0, commas = 0,n=0;
    int  i = 0, cnt = 0;
    char        *s=NULL;
    int        signCount=0;
    puts("Enter the Currency");
    gets_s(currency,20);

    n = strspn(currency+1, "0");                            //to find number of zeros present in the array. 

    if (currency[n] == '.' || currency[n]=='\0' )         //for Condtion like 0000000 or 000000.123 so as to maintain one zero so that o/p will be 0 or 0.123
    {

        memmove(currency, currency + n, strlen(currency));
    }
    else
    {
        memmove(currency, currency + n, strlen(currency));
    }

signCount==1?currency[0]='-':NULL;

    (s = strchr(currency, '.')) ? (length = s - currency) : (length = strlen(currency));   // Considering decimal Point and restricing to Put commas after decimal Point


    if (length>3)
    commas = (length / 2) - 1;                                                            // No of Commas to put 

    tmpCurrency = (char*)malloc((length + commas+1) * (sizeof(char*))); 

    while (currency[i] != '\0')
    {
        if (cnt == commas)   //maintaining count to check how many commas have been put in the character array
        {
            tmpCurrency[j] = currency[i];
            i++;
            j++;
            continue;
        }
          if (length % 2 == 0)                            //When length is even comma comes after 1 digit eg 1,23,456. so what i have done adjusting length ann checking when it is becoming even and putting comma.
        {
            tmpCurrency[j] = currency[i];
            if (currency[i] != '-' && currency[i+1]!='.')
            {
               tmpCurrency[j = j + 1] = ',';
            }
            i++;
            j++;
            length = length - 1;
            cnt++;
         }
        if (length % 2 != 0)         //for odd length putting one element in tmpCurrency and then subtracting length to make it even. 
        {
            tmpCurrency[j] = currency[i];
            i++;
            j++;
            length = length - 1;
        }
    }

    tmpCurrency[j] = '\0';
    strcpy_s(currency,20, tmpCurrency);
    puts(currency);
    free(tmpCurrency);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Bitwise operator will help to Optimize the code?

Comment: `gets_s(currency)` doesn't look right (`gets_s` requires 2 arguments). Please double check.

Comment: Yes it takes size as first parameter.I will be implementing in CGI so it won't be a Problem.

Comment: Please provide **working code** (at very least code that compiles). There are multiple omissions here (get_s, signCount, include files, just to mention few)

Comment: This Code is working.You can compile it. Include header files it will be working

Comment: As already noted gets_s() has a different prototype. Same for strcpy_s. Where signCount is defined? Headers are important (and a compilable snippet is  required when length is not an issue) About inclusions... you cast return value of malloc...

Comment: Why do you need to write a function for this when you already have `printf()`?  For example, using the `printf` program (which is a small wrapper around the library call): `LC_NUMERIC=en_IN printf "%'.3f\n" -12345678.901` produces `-1,23,45,678.901` exactly as you require.

Comment: this code is working still it has been put on hold and i have made all the changes necessary. It would be great if someone can tell me what other changes i should make

Answer (score 3):

1. Allocation woes. `char *tmpCurrency` needs enough memory for a null character terminated *string*.  This implies a +1 to the `length + commas` addition.  The cast of `malloc()` is not needed.  Multiplying by the size of a pointer `sizeof(char*)` is wrong.  It should be by the size of an element of `tmpCurrency`, which is a `char`.  `length,commas` should be `size_t` rather than `int`, but that make s little difference  with small strings.

   ```
   // tmpCurrency = (char*) malloc((length + commas) * (sizeof(char*)));
   tmpCurrency = malloc(sizeof *tmpCurrency * (length + commas + 1));
   ```
2. Separate out functional code from the test driver.  I'd expect some stand-alone function `Devious_ICF(char *dest, const char *src)` and then code in `main()` testing it.
3. Questionable space size and incorrect use of `gets_s(char *s, rsize_t n)`.  Avoid coding naked magic numbers like 20

   ```
   // char        currency[20];
   // gets_s(currency);

   #define CURRENCY_SIZE 20
   ...
   char currency[CURRENCY_SIZE];
   gets_s(currency, sizeof currency);
   ```
4. `stdout` is not certainly output as a prompt before asking for input.  To maintain portability, flush.

   ```
   puts("Enter the Currency");
   fflush(stdout);  // add
   gets_s(...);
   ```
5. Curious use of `static`.  `static` not needed here.

   ```
   // static int  i = 0, cnt = 0;
   int  i = 0, cnt = 0;
   ```
6. Accessing code outside array bounds.

   ```
   // memmove(currency, currency + n, strlen(currency));
   memmove(currency, currency + n, strlen(currency) - n);
   currency[n] = '\0';
   ```
7. Use of `?:` does not certainly use a consistent type as the types of `currency[0]='-'` and `NULL` may differ.  An `if()` would be better anyways.

   ```
   // signCount==1?currency[0]='-':NULL;
   if (signCount==1) {
     currency[0] = '-';
   }
   ```
8. Format to presentation width.  Use an auto formatter.  Weak formatting employed significantly detracts from code's presentation.

   ```
             if (length % 2 == 0)                            //When length is even comma comes after 1 digit eg 1,23,456. so what i have done adjusting length ann checking when it is becoming even and putting comma.
   ```

versus

```
          // When length is even, comma comes after 1 digit e.g. 1,23,456. 
          //   so what i have done adjusting length and checking when it is 
          //   becoming even and putting comma.
          if (length % 2 == 0)
```

9. Incorrect use of `errno_t strcpy_s(char * restrict s1, rsize_t s1max, const char * restrict s2);`.  Missing parameter.

   ```
   strcpy_s(currency, tmpCurrency);`
   ```
10. Missing `#include` headers.
11. Overall - approach used is excessively complex.

Given above issues that a compiler should have reported, it implies compilation is not done with warning fully enabled or code is using non-standard C.  Recommend fully enabling all warnings.